# R: Create a vector with all Keyboard constants

Tags: r

I want to create a vector that contains every constant in a QWERTY keyboard. For now I have:

```
keyboard <- c(LETTERS, letters, 0:9)
```

I need to add an element to the vector containing all the symbols (e.g. @, !, ?, etc...) Is there an R constant (such as LETTERS for all upper case letters in the alphabet) that contains all the symbols? If not, is there a fast way of getting them without typing them one by one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ascii printable characters are represented by 32 through 126.  We can generate that vector, convert to 'raw', then use a function to change to the actual characters.  After that we just break the string into pieces.

```
strsplit(rawToChar(as.raw(32:126)), "")[[1]]
```

which gives

```
> strsplit(rawToChar(as.raw(32:126)), "")[[1]]
 [1] " "  "!"  "\"" "#"  "$"  "%"  "&"  "'"  "("  ")"  "*"  "+"  ","  "-"  "." 
[16] "/"  "0"  "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  ":"  ";"  "<"  "=" 
[31] ">"  "?"  "@"  "A"  "B"  "C"  "D"  "E"  "F"  "G"  "H"  "I"  "J"  "K"  "L" 
[46] "M"  "N"  "O"  "P"  "Q"  "R"  "S"  "T"  "U"  "V"  "W"  "X"  "Y"  "Z"  "[" 
[61] "\\" "]"  "^"  "_"  "`"  "a"  "b"  "c"  "d"  "e"  "f"  "g"  "h"  "i"  "j" 
[76] "k"  "l"  "m"  "n"  "o"  "p"  "q"  "r"  "s"  "t"  "u"  "v"  "w"  "x"  "y" 
[91] "z"  "{"  "|"  "}"  "~"
```